# How to create a for loop and fill an output matrix in r

Tags: r, for-loop, output

This is a two part question.

I have a data set that is 2x6 named Price.

I want to create a for loop that will multiply specific rows within Price by (1-h) and -1*(1-h).  The results of this should fill a new matrix that is only 2x3.

The input of Price has values in the first column of rows 1-3, and values in the second column of rows 4-6.  The other values are just zeros.

```
h <- .02

> Price
     V1   V2
1 15.24 0.00
2 15.24 0.00
3 15.24 0.00
4  0.00 8.76
5  0.00 8.76
6  0.00 8.76
```

The new matrix should look as the following:

```
> effective.price
     V1    V2
1 14.94 -8.58
2 15.24 -8.76
3 15.24 -8.76
```

I don't even know where to begin, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the `h` is but I think this does what you want.

```
df <- read.table(text = "V1   V2
1 15.24 0.00
2 15.24 0.00
3 15.24 0.00
4  0.00 8.76
5  0.00 8.76
6  0.00 8.76")
h <- 0.02
df$V1 <- df$V1 * (1 - h)
df$V2 <-  - df$V2 * (1 - h)
effective.price <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) x[x != 0]))
```

This gives:

```
       V1      V2
1 14.9352 -8.5848
2 14.9352 -8.5848
3 14.9352 -8.5848
```

Comment: I used this approach and then specified exact points to change. Can you briefly explain what is happening within the lapply function?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `lapply` step strips out the zeros from each variable and puts it back into a `data.frame`. It would be like doing `a <- df$V1[df$V1 != 0]`, `b <- df$V2[df$V2 != 0]` and then `effective.price <- data.frame(a, b)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's easier than you think. If you really have a fixed input like that, then

```
price <- read.table(text = "15.24 0.00
                    15.24 0.00
                    15.24 0.00
                    0.00 8.76
                    0.00 8.76
                    0.00 8.76")
newPrice <- as.data.frame(cbind(price$V1[1:3],price$V2[4:6]))
```

where you are using column binds over set sections of your columns. The first column takes the values of V1[1 to 3], etc.

Yields

```
> newPrice
     V1   V2
1 15.24 8.76
2 15.24 8.76
3 15.24 8.76
```

If you need to change the value of the elements of `newPrice` you can operate on that in a vector fashion:

```
newPrice$V1 <- newPrice$V1 * (1 - h)
newPrice$V2 <- newPrice$V2 * (h - 1)
```

yielding

```
> newPrice
       V1      V2
1 14.9352 -8.5848
2 14.9352 -8.5848
3 14.9352 -8.5848
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with reshaping:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(V1 = V1 * (1-h),
         V2 = V2 * -(1-h),
         ID = n() %>% `/`(2) %>% seq %>% rep(2)) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -ID) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  spread(variable, value)
```